# GWTMockito: How to mock AutoBeanCodex?

Tags: gwt, mockito, autobean

I have tests which I am writing that use `AutoBeanCodex` to encode and decode *AutoBeans*. 
When I try to test methods which use `AutoBeanCodex.decode(...)`, I get errors like the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:     com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBean$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$78caf05b cannot be cast to com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl.doDecode(AutoBeanCodexImpl.java:549)
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanCodex.decode(AutoBeanCodex.java:39)
at ...
```

First question is **how** do I deal with `AutoBeanCodex` in my gwtmockito tests?

Do I have to use a fake provider like so, `GwtMockito.useProviderForType(Class, FakeProvider)`?

If there are multiple ways to deal with `AutoBeanCodex`, what is the best approach?

Comment: Filed an issue with the gwtmockito team, https://github.com/google/gwtmockito/issues/22.

Comment: Issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

A priori (I haven't used GwtMockito, yet), you should configure a `FakeProvider` for `AutoBeanFactory.class` to delegate to `AutoBeanFactorySource.create()` so that you get **real** AutoBean instances, that `AutoBeanCodex` should be able to serialize and deserialize.

You should probably raise an issue to GwtMockito so that this behavior is built-in, like for UiBinder et al.

Comment: I'll give that a try. And I will definitely raise the issue to GwtMockito. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use powermock for testing with statics. I've used it with gwtmockito both in a same test